# How to start with arraylists & classes

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist

I am an IT student and in my spare time I would like to make some apps in java and I was trying to work on one but don't know how to get started. I have the idea and it's a random player/team generator.

For example football, I would like a program that gives me a random player from an `array`. So I would think I have to make a `class`.

When it randomly generates a player it has to have the right team,

Example:

> Player:Messi. 
>      Team: FC Barcelona. 
>      Role: Attacker.

But how do I get started? can anyone help me on the way?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please first of all read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Check [help/on-topic]: _asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: @user2314737 OP actually didn't ask for any off-site resource. Just for advice. Not a good question, but it's the wrong close reason IMO. I tend to think either "Too Broad" or "Primarily Opinion Based".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

// Here is an example to get you started:

```
private static String[] playerNames = new String[] {"Messi", "Ronaldo"};
private static String[] teamNames = new String[] {"FC Barcelona", "Chelsea"};
private static String[] roleNames = new String[] {"Attacker", "Defender"};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    public List<Player> players;
    players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    players.add(new Player("Messi", "FC Barcelona", "Attacker"));
}

public Player getRandomPlayer() {
    Player player=null;
    String name = getRandomName();
    String team = getRandomTeam();
    String role = getRandomRole();
}

private String getRandomName() {
    return playerNames[new Random().nextInt(playerNames.length())];
}

private String getRandomTeam() {
    return teamNames[new Random().nextInt(teamNames.length())];
}

private String getRandomRole() {
    return roleNames[new Random().nextInt(roleNames.length())];
}
```

// class Player

```
public class Player {
    public String name;
    public String team;
    public String role;
    public Player(String name, String team, String role) {
        this.name = name;
        this.team = team;
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```